# Uploadify/jQuery, How could I display result of uploaded file?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I would like to see what prints in my server side script when it gets a file (via uploadify plugin in jQuery). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to [the official site](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) documentation section, you can find there

> The onComplete function allows you to
>   fire a custom function when each file
>   has completed uploading.

So your server side script could pass some data back to your jQuery script, so you could know what happening on the server. Also there onError events, so you are able to know about any errors

Or you can create some server log and trace there some information from your server side script(it could be DB, or simple text file), if you don't want user to know what happening on your server.

Comment: thx for answer, but what if my script just stopped at loading img? I would like to see what there was print anyway, in all cases.

Comment: @Josh well if it stop because of error you will receive an onError event. Also you have onProgess event, so you can track you upload progress with javaScript, and maybe calculate somehow if the upload process stuck on one place for long time. And as i sad if you really want to know everything that happens on your server you need to use some logging system.